# Full screen fragment and transparent TabLayout (Prisma)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm struggling with animation like you can see in Prisma app. I'm talking about animation between CAMERA and FEED. I need to set my fragment to full screen and in same time change TabLayout colour to transparent. Any suggestions? You can see it on this gif http://gph.is/2mWBPEf